# Purposefully exiting process for a dyno restart on heroku

Tags: heroku, phantomjs

I've got a phantomjs app (http://css.benjaminbenben.com) running on heroku - it works well for some time but then I have to run `heroku restart` because it requests start timing out.

I'm looking for a stop-gap solution (I've gone from around 6 to 4500 daily visitors over the last week), and I was considering exiting the process after it had served a set number of requests to fire a restart.

Will this work?  And would this be considered bad practice?

(in case you're interested, the app source is here - https://github.com/benfoxall/wtcss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd work, as long as you don't crash within I think 10 minutes of the last crash. If it's too frequent the process will stay down.

It's not bad practice, but it's not great practice. You should figure out what is causing your server to hang, of course.